# domU installation failed in xen

Tags: installation, xen

I am trying to install domU in xen. I get this error i can't understand that error and how to solve can any one explain and this error cause.

Here in the above error my machine cannot download the image file i desired to install. i am inside the proxy environment. it tried wget to iso of wheezy it not working. i need to give the iso from my local file system.

the command i used is

```
xen-create-image --hostname=machine-0 --memory=512mb --vcpus=2 --lvm=vg0 --dhcp --pygrub --dist=wheezy
```

how to give the image from local file system to the above command to install.

error from my log file:

```
Done
Installation method: debootstrap
Using /usr/sbin/debootstrap as debootstrap command

Copying files from host to image.
Copying files from /var/cache/apt/archives/ -> /tmp/cwlcFRPxgQ/var/cache/apt/archives
Done
Done
I: Retrieving Release
I: Retrieving Release.gpg
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id ED6D65271AACF0FF15D123036FB2A1C265FFB764)
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Retrieving Packages
E: Couldn't download dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
WARNING (/usr/bin/xt-install-image): The installed system at /tmp/cwlcFRPxgQ doesn't  seem to be a full system.
WARNING (/usr/bin/xt-install-image): The installed system is missing the common file: /bin/ls.
WARNING (/usr/bin/xt-install-image): The installed system at /tmp/cwlcFRPxgQ doesn't seem to be a full system.
WARNING (/usr/bin/xt-install-image): The installed system is missing the common file: /bin/cp.

Copying files from new installation to host.
Copying files from /tmp/cwlcFRPxgQ/var/cache/apt/archives -> /var/cache/apt/archives/
Done
Done
Done
System installation failed.  Aborting
umount: /tmp/cwlcFRPxgQ/proc: not found
Running command 'umount /tmp/cwlcFRPxgQ/proc 2>&1' failed with exit code 256.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

check if /etc/resolv.conf is "resolving" your dns.

resolv.conf should have at least a line saying

nameserver

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Your command creates a config file in /etc/xen pointing to the disk/image you created("--mirror=http: //cdn.debian.net/debian" should work). But if you already downloaded the image you should reference it in your config file: disk = [ 'tap:aio:/srv/xen/mailserver.img,xvda,w', ] .

[Centos example](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/InstallingCentOSDomU)
[block devices](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-xen_sd_draft/cha.xen.vbd.html)